# How to use map to check if each list element is inside any set of ranges? (TypeError: len() of unsized object)

Tags: python, pandas

I have a list of elements and I want to use mapping functions to generate an element-wise list of whether they are within any ranges in a list of ranges. I already have a solution that uses a for-loop, but for-loops are too slow because both my element and range lists will be much larger.

Here is my code so far:

```
import pandas as pd

# check element-wise if [1,0,45,60] within ranges 1-10, 21-30, or 41-50
# expected output: true, false, true, false
s = pd.Series([1,0,45,60])
f = lambda x: any((x >= pd.Series([1,20,40])) & (x <= pd.Series([10,30,50])))
print map(f, s)
```

Error:

```
    elif isinstance(other, (np.ndarray, pd.Index)):
-->     if len(self) != len(other):
            raise ValueError('Lengths must match to compare')
              return self._constructor(na_op(self.values, np.asarray(other)),

TypeError: len() of unsized object
```

Comment: Are there any properties of those ranges (mutually exclusive, constant length etc). Wouldn't it be better to sort them and check for the closest one, instead of using `any`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out. Seems like everything works and is still fast if I convert to numpy. Normally I'd frown on introducing a new library but pandas is built on top of numpy.

```
import pandas as pd, numpy as np

s = pd.Series([1,0,45,60])
mins = np.array(pd.Series([1,20,40]))
maxes = np.array(pd.Series([10,30,50]))
f = lambda x: np.any((x >= mins) & (x <= maxes))
print map(f, s)
```

Comment: Actually, there is an even faster method using pandas indexing and loc. I'll post a solution here when I have a chance.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can first create all ranges and for check use [`isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isin.html) with [`tolist`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.tolist.html):

```
import pandas as pd

s = pd.Series([1,0,45,60])
print s
0     1
1     0
2    45
3    60
dtype: int64

rng = range(1,11) + range(21,31) + range(41,51)
print rng
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 
 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50]

print s.isin(rng) 
0     True
1    False
2     True
3    False
dtype: bool

print s.isin(rng).tolist()
[True, False, True, False]
```

EDIT:

For creating ranges you can use [`numpy.arange`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.arange.html) and [`numpy.concatenate`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html):

```
import numpy as np

rng = np.concatenate((np.arange(1, 11), np.arange(21, 31), np.arange(41, 51)))
print rng
[ 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 21 22 23 24 25 
 26 27 28 29 30 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50]
```

Another solution for generating `ranges` can be slicing:

```
s = range(0,51)
print s
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 
 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 
 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50]

print s[1:11] + s[21:31] + s[41:51]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 21, 22, 23, 24,  25, 
 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50]
```

Comment: Thanks for your thorough answer! Since I will a large list of ranges, I'd have to use a for-loop to construct the ranges, which I mentioned in my question is something I'd like to avoid. More importantly, this solution (if it uses int32) could mean building a 2^32-element array, which is enourmous (17 GB). I appreciate your comments on constructing ranges. I haven't considered slicing this way before.

Answer (score 0):

you can use [cut()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.cut.html) function for categorizing your values:

```
In [296]: s[pd.cut(s, bins=range(0, 110, 10), labels=labels).isin(['1 - 10','21 - 30','41 - 50'])]
Out[296]:
0     1
3    23
5    45
dtype: int64
```

Explanation:

original series:

```
In [291]: s
Out[291]:
0     1
1     0
2    19
3    23
4    35
5    45
6    60
dtype: int64
```

labels for categories:

```
In [292]: labels = [ "{0} - {1}".format(i, i + 9) for i in range(1, 100, 10) ]

In [293]: labels
Out[293]:
['1 - 10',
 '11 - 20',
 '21 - 30',
 '31 - 40',
 '41 - 50',
 '51 - 60',
 '61 - 70',
 '71 - 80',
 '81 - 90',
 '91 - 100']
```

using `cut()` for categorizing your series:

```
In [294]: pd.cut(s, bins=range(0, 110, 10), labels=labels)
Out[294]:
0     1 - 10
1        NaN
2    11 - 20
3    21 - 30
4    31 - 40
5    41 - 50
6    51 - 60
dtype: category
Categories (10, object): [1 - 10 < 11 - 20 < 21 - 30 < 31 - 40 ... 61 - 70 < 71 - 80 < 81 - 90 <
                          91 - 100]
```

select only *intereseting* categories:

```
In [295]: pd.cut(s, bins=range(0, 110, 10), labels=labels).isin(['1 - 10','21 - 30','41 - 50'])
Out[295]:
0     True
1    False
2    False
3     True
4    False
5     True
6    False
dtype: bool
```

and finally:

```
In [296]: s[pd.cut(s, bins=range(0, 110, 10), labels=labels).isin(['1 - 10','21 - 30','41 - 50'])]
Out[296]:
0     1
3    23
5    45
dtype: int64
```